# batch if not exist takes out drive letter from variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

Batch File:

```
@echo off

echo.
echo Verifying existence of File

for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1 (
     set BDCPATH=%%d:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1
    ) else if exist %%d:\dir1_2\dir2\dir3\file1 (
     set BDCPATH=%%d:\dir1_2\dir2\dir3\file1
    )
)

echo %BDCPATH%
echo %BDCPATH%

IF NOT EXIST %BCDPATH% echo %BCDPATH%

goto :eof
```

When I echo the '%BDCPATH% variable, it takes out the drive letter. Can you explain why this happens and a fix for this?

cmd output:

```
c:\Tools\KDNET_Helper>C:\Users\c_jamesp\Desktop\test1.bat

Verifying existence of BCD File
i:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1
i:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1
dir1\dir2\dir3\file1
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the correct batch file?  The sample output does not quite match the shown script (the first echo in the script does not say "BCD File", while the sample output does).  Just checking in case it is not a cut-n-paste error in the post.

Comment: Yes, thats why I am asking the question here, because this should work. The third line should be "i:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1", and not "dir1\dir2\dir3\file1". To reproduce the error, just create the directories in an external hard drive, and the file. Then run the batch script.

Comment: I am referring to the line `echo Verifying existence of File`.  The output says `Verifying existence of **BCD** File`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: the quotes fix an issue with certain path names, and the parentheses are changed.

Note that if neither of those path\file exists then the variable will not be set.

```
@echo off

echo.
echo Verifying existence of File
set "bcdpath="
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist "%%d:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1" (
     set "BDCPATH=%%d:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1"
    ) else ( 
     if exist "%%d:\dir1_2\dir2\dir3\file1" set "BDCPATH=%%d:\dir1_2\dir2\dir3\file1"
   )
 )

echo "%BDCPATH%"
echo "%BDCPATH%"

IF NOT EXIST "%BCDPATH%" echo "%BCDPATH%"

if not defined bcdpath echo no files found
pause
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

good guess, but by spending more time playing around I found out two things:

```
@echo off

echo.
echo Verifying existence of File

for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1 (
     set BDCPATH=%%d:\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1
    ) else if exist %%d:\dir1_2\dir2\dir3\file1 (
     set BDCPATH=%%d:\dir1_2\dir2\dir3\file1
    )
)



echo %BDCPATH%
echo %BDCPATH%

IF NOT EXIST %BDCPATH% echo %BDCPATH%


:eof
```

1. I had `%BCDPATH%` instead of `%BDCPATH%`
2. It should just be either `goto somename` and not `goto :somename`.